# How to find cause of 'Transform with key of "perspective" cannot be zero: {"perspective":0}'

Tags: android, react-native

I'm taking over care and feeding of an existing React-native app. There's a part of the app that takes a picture, which results in the message "Transform with key of "perspective" cannot be zero: {"perspective":0}". (This happens in the Android emulator.)

In the existing code, there's no place that designates a perspective. I'm curious what might be implicitly expecting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was happening. The code was rendering a FlipCard (@see [react-native-flip-card](https://github.com/moschan/react-native-flip-card)) FlipCard takes an attribute "perspective," whose default is zero. Setting it to something *other* than zero saved the day: `...<FlipCard perspective={0.5}...>`

Hope this helps someone.